# Mongoose: Find document where field of type array contain a value in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql, mongoose-schema

I have this model:

```
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  help_offers: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "help_offers",
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model("profiles", ProfileSchema);
```

I have been trying to find profiles where help_offers contains a value from a provided array. I have tried a different combination of `$in`, `$elemMatch`, `$all` and they all return wrong results.

```
const getProfilesWithDirtyHelpOffers =
  async function getProfilesWithDirtyHelpOffers(dirty_help_offers_ids) {
    const profile_search_option = {
      help_offers: { $all: dirty_help_offers_ids },
      // help_offers: { $elemMatch: { $in: dirty_help_offers_ids } },
    };

    const profiles_with_dirty_help_offers = await Profile.find(
      profile_search_option
    ).populate("help_offers");

    const response = {
      profiles_with_dirty_help_offers: {
        data: profiles_with_dirty_help_offers,
        length: profiles_with_dirty_help_offers.length,
      },
    };
    return response;
  };
```

The result contains profiles with `help_offers` that don't exist in the `dirty_help_offers_ids` array.
Any idea what's going-on here?

---

**EDIT 1:** Using `$in` like this, actually works:

```
   const profile_search_option = {
      help_offers: { $in: dirty_help_offers_ids },
    };
```

Comment: can you show some example document and expected result, see this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Auvb5O7tYqu) with your query.

Comment: Are you trying only match documents that only contain matching help_offers, or do you want all documents that have any matches, but filter the array to only those offers that match?

Comment: I want to get all profiles with help_offers that contain ANY value from the provided array. I just tested with $in, in the playground. It seems to be working fine.